# joining DataStreams in Apache Flink

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have 2 DataStreams in Apache Flink from Flink Training [RidesAndFares exercise](https://github.com/apache/flink-training/tree/master/rides-and-fares)

```
TaxiRide stream () rideId, taxiId, driverId, ...

TaxiFare stream () rideId, isStart, startTime, endTime, startLon, ...
```

I tried to join them as

```
  rides
    .join(fares)
    .where(r => r.rideId)
    .equalTo(f => f.rideId)
    .window(TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.milliseconds(2)))
    .apply {(r, f) => (r,f)}
```

The test is OK, but in the [solution](https://github.com/apache/flink-training/blob/master/rides-and-fares/src/solution/scala/org/apache/flink/training/solutions/ridesandfares/scala/RidesAndFaresSolution.scala) I found join with `RichCoFlatMapFunction` and could you help me understand:

1. the difference between this way
2. which type of Window uses `RichCoFlatMapFunction` (Tumbling, Sliding, Session,    Interval)
3. how `.join` can work with state (to put something)

Comment: What do you mean by "work with state"? Saving info accross joins?

Comment: 2. It works with any type of windows. Joins are not window dependant.

Answer (score 0):

The reference solution to this exercise is implemented with a `RichCoFlatMapFunction` because the objective of the exercise is to show how to work with some of the lower-level mechanisms: namely keyed state and connected streams.

By the way, typically when joins are implemented "by hand" one will use a `KeyedCoProcessFunction` rather than a `RichCoFlatMap` in order to have access to timers as well as state. But at the point in the Flink tutorials where we introduce this particular exercise, we haven't yet talked about process functions and timers.

None of the built-in window types are implemented as a `RichCoFlatMapFunction`, but the windowed joins are somewhat similar in that they are also using a two-input operator. The `ProcessJoinFunction` that you provide in the `apply` method is a kind of `RichFunction` with two input streams, and it can be made stateful in the same way as any other `RichFunction`.